# JQuery refusing to read values from a dictionary returned form API

Tags: jquery

I have a page which calls an API and reads the response using JQuery. This is the code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#fund_search").keyup(function(){
        var query_string = $("#fund_search").val();
        console.log(query_string)
        if(query_string.length < 6){
            $("#result").text("")
        }
        if(query_string.length >= 6){
            query_string = parseInt(query_string)
            var query = {"amfi_code": query_string}
                $.ajax({ 
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/latestreturn",
                    data: JSON.stringify(query), 
                    contentType: 'json',
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res)
                        $.each(res, function(i, item){
                            console.log(item.year_t),
                            console.log(item.year_f),
                            console.log(item.year_o)
                        })
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
                    }.bind(this)
            }); 
        }  
    })
});
```

the line `console.log(res)` prints the dictionary in the console, but when I print specific keys, it returns undefined.

[image]

I am using this exact same code block on another page with a different API and it works perfectly there. But when I copy paste the code here, as soon as I change the keys, it stops working.

It's worth noting that I'm more of a Python person and am trying to create this page just as a basic front-end for my API. I do not have much knowledge of JQuery and I have copied this code from an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the response `res` isn't an array, `$.each` will cycle on object keys.

as a side note, probably it should append a single `<tr>`

```
const object = {
  data: 'abc'
}

$.each(object, (i, item) => {
  // outputs 'data', 'abc'
  console.log(i, item)
})
```

What you're trying to achieve could be this:

```
success: function(res) {
  console.log(res.year_t);
  console.log(res.year_f);
  console.log(res.year_o);
}
```

Or, if the `res` becomes an array, this other example

```
const object = [{
  data: 'foo'
}, {
  data: 'bar'
}]

$.each(object, (index, item) => {
  console.log(item.data)
})
```